# Double integral over X * bivariate normal

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to compute the integral of (bivariate normal distribution times X) over the limits X = {-inf, inf} and Y = {0, inf}.

[image]

Using the double integration calculator in Wolfram Alpha, I enter this. [Note that I am not including limits, since Wolfram Alpha is unable to return a result when I do so].

```
x/(2 * π * (s1) * (s2) * sqrt(1 - p^2)) * exp[-((x^2)/((s1)^2) - (2 * p * x * y)/((s1) * (s2)) + (y^2)/((s2)^2))/(2(1 - p^2))]
```

I know numerically that this integral should be finite. But Wolfram Alpha is returning an "Exact Result" with that appears to be infinite (unless I am misinterpreting something).

[image]

Specifically, I first plug in {X=inf, Y=inf} into the above equation and get zero. And then when I plug {X=-inf, Y=0} into the above equation, I get something infinite. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write `Sqrt` and `Exp`  with capital letters. See result:

```
f = x/(2*π*(s1)*(s2)*Sqrt[1 - p^2])*
      Exp[-((x^2)/((s1)^2) - (2*p*x*y)/((s1)*(s2)) + (y^2)/((s2)^2))/(2 (1 - p^2))];

Integrate[f, {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> p ∈ Reals && s1 > 0 && s2 > 0]

(*   ConditionalExpression[(p s1)/Sqrt[2 π], 0 < p < 1]   *)
```